# How to costumize ComboBox in WPF (items list)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**So far I was able to customize my ComboBox to appear in rounded corners by editing the style but the list Items doesn't appear if I click on it:**

```xml
<Style x:Key="RoundedCombeBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Fill="#FFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Inter_Font" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="20,10,20,0"/> 
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I though that my problem maybe because of me using a TextBox. if that's the problem then what's the best way of doing it or how to make textbox suggest and append items?

Comment: You could do a google search on "combobox autocomplete c# wpf" to see how it could be done!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round combobox style wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028469/round-combobox-style-wpf)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I believe you can find what you need from this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcombobox%5D+round). Please add more information if you need help.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727879/how-to-change-the-cornerradius-of-the-combobox-wpf